# Searching for a string with double quotes inside of square brackets

Tags: regex, sed

I am using SED in my build file and wish to replace:

- $response["foo"][0]["bar"]

  with
- 'b343443-45454-dfdf4545-trnj5ff56t'

Currently I have:

s@\$response["foo"][0]["bar"]@\'b343443-45454-dfdf4545-trnj5ff56t\'

However, SED seems to not like the double quotes. I have tried escaping them as well but get the same issue. Can someone point out how i might better construct this expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

double quotes are not problem, you need to escape the `[ ]`:

```
echo '$response["foo"][0]["bar"]'|sed 's/\$response\["foo"\]\[0\]\["bar"\]/\x27b343443-45454-dfdf4545-trnj5ff56t\x27/'                                           
'b343443-45454-dfdf4545-trnj5ff56t'
```

Comment: Actually, I had escaped the brackets and neglected to add that. Even escaped, I am getting an issue. If i remove the double quotes, and replace it with single quotes i don't get an issue (other than it searching for the wrong thing). The double quotes inside the brackets do not appear to be interpreted as part of the string I am searching for.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue and probably would have done so sooner if I had posted in the correct place. As mentioned, this is a SED command within a build file (XML file). The double quotes needed to be written as **&quot**; to be read correctly. So, this is really something i should have sought out in the PHING group rather than the SED group. Whoops!